# Cant create a taxonamy menu block

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Steps i followed

1. Created a vocabulary (V) and added 5 taxonomy terms to it.
2. Created a new menu (M).
3. In edit vocabulary (created before), selected Menu M as Menu location from Taxonomy menu
   settings.
4. Hit Save button.

Getting this error

The Taxonomy Menu rebuild process encountered an error.

An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: /batch?id=688&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText:

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be answered here. It seems to be a call to Drupals Batch API that fails. But why can't be answered without some debugging and is not in the scope of your question.

Basically you are doing it right. You can try the otherway round and add menu items to you desired menu and than let them point to taxonomy/term/123. This should give you the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. if i made taxonomy items as a separate menu, there should be a rework to update the items to menu. Need to create taxonomy first then to create menu item for it. If its a taxonomy, single update will be enough. Can you point out some possibilities for  Drupals Batch API fail. It will be useful for me to fix the bug.